# TOpenDialog does not change modal level

Tags: delphi, winapi, modal-dialog

I am trying to identify if a TCommonDialog (Open, Save etc) is active in my application but they do not appear to trigger `OnModalBegin` or change `Application.ModalLevel` despite clearly having modal status.

I am intercepting keyboard events in my application and I want to pass through these keyboard events under some conditions. One of the conditions to do the pass through is a dialog box being open but I can't find a way to detect this.

Is there a way to know when a decedent of `TCommonDialog` is active?

Comment: The common dialogs are OS dialogs, not modal `TForm` windows, that is why they do not trigger the `OnModal...` events or affect the `ModalLevel`

Comment: Do not pass through keyboard events when your [main]form is disabled.

Comment: .. and if you test for "IsWindowEnabled" instead of "Enabled", you can also account for modal API dialogs like "MessageBox", not just common dialog wrappers.

Comment: The issue is that its a multi window application so I am intercepting the keyboard to do something independent of the window the user is in. I just dont want the intercept when a open/save dialog is being used. "IsWindowEnabled" would require me to test all possible windows in my app (and maybe that is the necessary solution but it sounds excessive).